# Processing.js Threading

Tags: javascript, ajax, processing.js

I have a function in my processing.js file that calls for an AJAX script to return an array with which I want to define some simple starting variables for my code. I want this function to complete before any other part of the code that comes after it is executed. 
When i run my code both the alerts in the setup() phase and the first alert in the draw() return "undefined" while the next iterations in the draw() phase return the actual array I need.

The processing code:

```
var loadArray;

setup() {

  loadArray = new Array();

  js_GetArray(function(data) {
        loadArray = data;
    });

    alert(loadArray[1]);
    alert(loadArray[2]);
}

void draw()
{  
    alert(loadArray[k]);
    k++;
}
```

The AJAX:

```
<!-- Read the vars numbers from the mysql database and return them -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function js_GetArray(callback) {
        $.get( "load.php", function( actiondata ) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(actiondata);
            callback(obj);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Is there a way to force the program to complete the js_GetArray call before moving on to the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is during loading of the page, then what about using a flag as indication that the call has returned?

```
var loadArray;
var isloaded = false;

setup() {

  loadArray = new Array();

  js_GetArray(function(data) {
        loadArray = data;
        isloaded = true;
        alert(loadArray[1]);
        alert(loadArray[2]);
    });
}

void draw()
{  
    if(isloaded)
    {
        alert(loadArray[k]);
        k++;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I have moved the alerts inside the callback function.

Comment: This solution solves the issue for the alerts in the draw() phase but the while loop causes the program to enter a loop it doesn't leave and get stuck.

Comment: sidenote: don't use alert. Use `console.log` because why on earth would you block the entire page rendering thread? Also, don't use `... = new Array()`, just use `... = []`, JS has dedicated syntax for this, which rather than "syntactic sugar" is actually intentional.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer to the one given, I've covered this on the processingjs.org website extensively, so you probably want to give that a read: http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html#interface